# Add Queue to OpenJMS

Tags: java, openjms

at the moment I am playing around a little bit with openJMS. I already got the examples working, but in that cases I have to add / edit the queues and topics in the admin-page.

Is it possible - and how - to add queues dynamically while openJMS is running? What I want to do is, creating and destroying objects at runtime that can describe to the JMS and have their own point-to-point queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer by my self, it's rather good described on the official usersguide - why didn't I find it first?

http://openjms.sourceforge.net/usersguide/admin.html

Comment: shall I delete the whole question as it's not more interesting or shall i let it stand out as is?

Comment: I know it's been a while since you posted this,but the link you provided helped me finish my college assignment.
Thanks a bunch!